# Error code: DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure, csv, delimiter, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from a csv file to a sql table in Azure Data Factory
This is my type property for the CSV file

```
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": "2020-09-16-stations.csv",
                "container": "container"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
```

I recieve following error:

`ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source '2020-09-16-stations.csv' with row number 2: found more columns than expected column count 11.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'`

This is row #2

`0e18d0d3-ed38-4e7f,Station2,Mainstreet33,,12207,Berlin,48.1807,11.4609,1970-01-01 01:00:00+01,"{""openingTimes"":[{""applicable_days"":96,""periods"":[{""startp"":""08:00"",""endp"":""20:00""}]},{""applicable_days"":31,""periods"":[{""startp"":""06:00"",""endp"":""20:00""}]}]}"`

I think the last column, the JSON query is making trouble in this case. When I view the data it looks fine:
[image]

I thought exactly the `"quoteChar": "\""`would prevent that the last column makes problems. I have no idea why I am getting this error while i run debug

Comment: Try setting the escape character = " (a double quote)

Comment: Surprisingly that helped. I didn't now what the escape character has to do with it. You can answer the question with your comment now if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the escape character = " (a double quote). This should treat each pair of double quotes as an actual single quote and wont consider them as a "Quote Char" within the string, so you will end up with a string that looks like this (and which the system knows is a single string and not something it has to split):

```
{"openingTimes":[{"applicable_days":96,"periods":[{"startp":"08:00","endp":"20:00"}]},
{"applicable_days":31,"periods":[{"startp":"06:00","endp":"20:00"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because this value `"{""openingTimes"":[{""applicable_days"":96,""periods"":[{""startp"":""08:00"",""endp"":""20:00""}]},{""applicable_days"":31,""periods"":[{""startp"":""06:00"",""endp"":""20:00""}]}]}"` contains several comma and your columnDelimiter is "," which leads to that value is split to several column. So you need to change your columnDelimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that but the whole value is wrapped in 2 ```"``` and I defined "quoteChar": "\"" which would anticipate the last column as one and wouldn't separate them again.